# What does the blue elevator (?) in this picture refer to?

Tags: doctor-who, time-travel, spaceship, robots

From [graphjam](http://graphjam.memebase.com/2011/05/05/funny-graphs-trust-me/),

[image: Venn diagram of time travel, spaceships and killer robots with the blue elevator in the middle]

Can anybody tell me what the elevator refers to in the picture?

Comment: Also, [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2585/where-to-start-with-dr-who) may be relevant to your interests. :)

Comment: Surely there were killer robots at least once in Star Trek?

Comment: The Borg and Lore come to mind.

Comment: Although for TOS, there was the *What Are Little Girls Made Of?* robots too, but they're not the usual killer robots.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That's not an elevator, it's the [TARDIS](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Tardis).  Its external appearance is an old [Police Box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_box).  It's [The Doctor's](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_doctor) (from the UK tv show *Doctor Who*) time and space travel vehicle.  The Doctor has several killer robot nemeses, such as [Cybermen](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Cybermen) and [Daleks](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Dalek) (edit: Per the comment, the Daleks aren't actually robots, but cyborgs).  Those links should point you to much more information on the subject.

Comment: Also, Dr. Who's seasons are mostly now on Netflix streaming, so give it a chance. I grew up with Star Wars and Star Trek, BSG, and even The Terminator. "Dr. Who" was always something I'd heard of but never seen... until last year. If you like any of those shows, give Dr. Who a shot - you'll love it.

Comment: Wow, thanks to your wikipedia link, I just learned there's a genuine, old "TARDIS-style" police box less than a mile from where I live. I know where I'm going to geek out this weekend!

Comment: Daleks are not robots, they are just cyborgs.

Comment: @svick. Yes you are right that the Daleks are not robots. I think the implication is that they are also one step down from cyborgs. They are living things trapped inside a machine - a travel machine. This makes them even more scary than the standard cyborgs.

Comment: Same applies for cybermen

Comment: Given that the OP includes the Dr Who tag, bit weird that they don't recognise this?

Answer (score 8):

It's a UK telephone box for police. In the 50's and 60's (and maybe before) it was used in the same way that police would use radios now. That is, if they needed to contact base they would find the nearest "Police Box" which would have a telephone in it. It would also contain other items that would be of use to the police. For obvious reasons it is not seen any more in the UK. I remember, vaguely, seeing one alongside a motorway. But they are all gone now. There are a few similarly related telephone items about the place - but not many.

Edit:

It looks like there are a couple of Tardis style police boxes still around. The photo below is from Earls Court tube station. It was actually erected in 1997 - and I think it has become quite a tourist attraction. I will be heading off there ASAP and taking some friends who have never seen a Police Box. :)

Here's a picture of the last one in London, in the style that most inspired the *Doctor Who* TARDIS. *(courtesy of [Loïc Wolff](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/293/loic-wolff))*

[image: London police box]

*[Christi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1459/christi) notes:* Edinburgh is the only place I've ever seen actual police boxes still around. They are a slightly different design to the ones in Dr. Who.

[image: Edinburgh police box]

There were also police telephone posts:

[image: police telephone posts]

A real Police Box in use:

[image: Police Box in use]

Actually - I'm reading that there is quite a few still preserved in Glasgow. Some seem to have been converted to "Coffee Shops".[image: Glasgow Police Box Coffee Shop]

You can see here that it is blue - as we would expect. The funny thing is that Police Boxes in Glasgow were traditionally red and not blue.

[image: Red Police Box]

Comment: in the episode "The Bells of St. John", one of the protagonist, searching for the TARDIS in london, said something like "we made fool of ourself at Earls Court".